# Published Event not being subscribed or Published

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

When I am trying to publish an events from SimpleFreeDrawModifier class to FieldSettingViewModel class, Subscriber class not able to get subscribe the events or vice versa.

**Publishing Events Code**:

```
  public SimpleFreeDrawModifier(RegionManager regionManager, EventAggregator eventAggragator)  // Constructor 
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _eventAggragator = eventAggragator;

        CorodinatesMapDictionary =new Dictionary<object, object>();
    }
     private void AppendPoint(Point mousePoint)
    {
        // On Mouse-down, append another point
        if (_dataSeries != null)
        {
             CorodinatesMapDictionary.Clear();
            _dataSeries.Append((double)XAxis.GetDataValue(mousePoint.X), (double)YAxis.GetDataValue(mousePoint.Y));
           
            GlobalVar.XCoordinate=(double)_dataSeries.XValues[0];
            GlobalVar.YCoordinate=(double)_dataSeries.YValues[0];

            CorodinatesMapDictionary.Add("X",  GlobalVar.XCoordinate);
            CorodinatesMapDictionary.Add("Y", GlobalVar.YCoordinate);

            var calc = Math.Abs(GlobalVar.XCoordinate) * 1.0913;
            if (GlobalVar.YCoordinate < 0)
            {
                if (GlobalVar.YCoordinate >= -(calc))
                {
                    _eventAggragator.GetEvent<MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents>().Publish();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(Math.Abs(GlobalVar.XCoordinate) <=25 && GlobalVar.YCoordinate <=25)
                {
                    _eventAggragator.GetEvent<MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents>().Publish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Subscribing Events Code**

```
  public FieldSettingViewModel(RegionManager regionManager,IEventAggregator eventAggragator)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _eventAggragator = eventAggragator;

        ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(Clear);
        ApplyFieldSettingCommand = new DelegateCommand(ApplyFieldSetting, canApplyFieldSetting);

        ScanAreaDataSeries = new XyDataSeries<double, double>();
      
        GetScanSeriesData();

        _eventAggragator.GetEvent<MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents>().Subscribe(MapValue);
    }
     private void MapValue()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Could you please provide any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does "not able to get subscribe the events or vice versa" mean? Do you get a compile error? A runtime Exception? Does the subscriber fail to get the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like instantiation of `SimpleFreeDrawModifier` and `FieldSettingViewModel` is achieved through dependency injection.

Are you sure that an instance of `FieldSettingViewModel` has been created and the it's receiving the same instance of `IEventAggregator`?

This minimal example without DI works

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using Prism.Events;

var eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

var pub = new Publisher(eventAggregator);
var sub = new Subscriber(eventAggregator);

pub.AppendPoint(new Point());


public class Publisher
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public Publisher(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)  // Constructor 
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

    }
    public void AppendPoint(Point mousePoint)
    {

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents>().Publish();
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public Subscriber(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents>().Subscribe(MapValue);
    }

    private void MapValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Map value called");
    }
}


internal class MapCoOrdinateChangedEvents : PubSubEvent
{
}
```

Check the DI lifetime of your EventAggregator is `Singleton` and not `Transient`, also try putting a breakpoint in the constructor of `FieldSettingViewModel` to ensure it is run.

If it's not being run and you're registering it for DI like `services.AddSingleton<FieldSettingViewModel>()`, try instead using `services.AddSingleton<FieldSettingViewModel>(new FieldSettingViewModel())` to ensure there is one instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of **SimpleFreeDrawModifier** use **EventAggregator** instead of the interface **IEventAggregator** therefore as precised by hwoodiwiss they are not using the same instance even if it has been registered as singleton.

It already happenned to me and it took me quite some time to see the missing I

Comment: Also, `RegionManager` instead of `IRegionManager`.